# unable to install sailsjs on cloud 9 ide

Tags: npm, sails.js, cloud9-ide

I get below errors

using node v0.10.22

> npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/Zolmeister/grunt-sails-linker.git
>   execvp(): No such file or directory

and

> npm ERR! Error: spawn ENOENT npm ERR!     at errnoException
>   (child_process.js:980:11) npm ERR!     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34) npm ERR!
>   If you need help, you may report this log at: npm ERR!
>   http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues npm ERR! or email it to: npm
>   ERR!
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.bz844450.x86_64 npm ERR!
>   command
>   "/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/c9-0.1/root/bin/node-openshift-v10"
>   "/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/c9-0.1/root/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js"
>   "-g" "install" "sails" npm ERR! cwd
>   /var/lib/stickshift/5296292f5973ca4984000011/app-root/data/694788 npm
>   ERR! node -v v0.10.22 npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8 npm ERR! syscall spawn npm
>   ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno ENOENT

with same node version my friend is able to install.

Comment: Did you try to just run the command `git clone git://github.com/Zolmeister/grunt-sails-linker.git` to see what happen?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem on cloud9 with a dependency on of one of my project on github. When I try the git clone command in the console it works perfectly fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it: Several people had this error on Github and all the answer are: "You need to install git". But git is installed on Cloud9 because as PierrOz said, a `git clone` works. The thing is that git and npm are not run from the same place:

`$ which git
/usr/bin/git
$ which npm
/var/lib/stickshift/some_random_uuid/app-root/data/bin/npm`

Putting a symlink of git in the directory where npm is run solved the issue for me:

`ln -s /usr/bin/git /var/lib/stickshift/some_random_uuid/app-root/data/bin/git`